# How to get users to see specific schemas only

Tags: sql-server, schema

Thanks for your time.

I need to have set of schemas which are to be viewed by single users or a group of users ( set in a role) and others should not have access to them. I don’t want to put each user to their department roles and then deny access to them as I give access to that department role. Can I change anything in public role to achieve this.

When I deny select in public for a particular schema, even the people who are granted the access can’t do select. Grant is taken over by Deny.using Mssqlserver.

Any help is appreciated

Edit: I’ll provide an example

Assume user1, user2, userA, userB
Schemas user1_schema, schema1, schema2

I want user1 only to be able to see user1_schema! I am aware if I deny select, etc to other other users on this schema, that would suffice. But, if I have 150 users, I dnt want to go on add them to each schema and deny access or when I have to add a user, go through several schemas to deny permissions at each schema level.

Initially I imagined if I deny access to public role, and grant access to a specific user/role along with it, it would work by denying access to everyone but let particular user/role have access. But i realised Deny trumps Grant and no one can access the schema.

Answer (score 0):

As I understood above question; there is need to isolate specific database schema user access for particular SQL login.

Here in below provided sample SQL, I have created **UserSchemaLogin** (which is SQL Login created prior have no role assigned and no access to any DB). Then below DCL statements would grant appropriate role to the specific **UserSchema** and deny access across other schemas (incl. **dbo** schema) in the database.

```
USE [YourDatabase]
GO

IF EXISTS(select 1 from sys.sysusers where [name] = 'UserSchemaLogin')
    DROP USER UserSchemaLogin ;
GO
CREATE USER [UserSchemaLogin] 
    FOR LOGIN [UserSchemaLogin]
    WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [UserSchema];
PRINT 'User Schema User [UserSchemaLogin] created successfully!' 
GO

ALTER AUTHORIZATION ON SCHEMA::[UserSchema] TO [dbo]
GO

GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::UserSchema TO UserSchemaLogin
GRANT CREATE SEQUENCE ON SCHEMA::UserSchema TO UserSchemaLogin;
GRANT DELETE ON SCHEMA::UserSchema TO UserSchemaLogin;
GRANT EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::UserSchema TO UserSchemaLogin;
GRANT INSERT ON SCHEMA::UserSchema TO UserSchemaLogin;
GRANT SELECT ON SCHEMA::UserSchema TO UserSchemaLogin;
GRANT UPDATE ON SCHEMA::UserSchema TO UserSchemaLogin;
GRANT VIEW CHANGE TRACKING ON SCHEMA::UserSchema TO UserSchemaLogin
GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::UserSchema TO UserSchemaLogin;

PRINT 'Schema User [UserSchemaLogin] has GRANTED Rights to Schema [UserSchema]' 
GO

DENY ALTER ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO UserSchemaLogin;
DENY CREATE SEQUENCE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO UserSchemaLogin;
DENY DELETE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO UserSchemaLogin;
DENY EXECUTE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO UserSchemaLogin;
DENY INSERT ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO UserSchemaLogin;
DENY SELECT ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO UserSchemaLogin;
DENY UPDATE ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO UserSchemaLogin;
DENY VIEW CHANGE TRACKING ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO UserSchemaLogin;
DENY VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::[dbo] TO UserSchemaLogin;

PRINT 'Schema User [UserSchemaLogin] has DENY Rights to Schema [dbo]' 
GO
```

Comment: But this would still mean other users will have access to the schema, since they are part of public

Comment: Its depends what role/rights assigned to other users/login. If other user/login does not allow to Schema1 but only Schema2, then above SQL need to be replace with schema2 for User2

Comment: Other users have access to all schemas. If I grant permissions for user1 to user1_schema, other users can still access it unless I deny each of their access at individual level. How do I avoid doing it for each user